# Blazor - How to trigger OnClickEvent without using Javascript

Tags: blazor-server-side

I want to trigger onclick event on input file control when I click on a different button. How can I achieve this?

I want to do something like this, but in Blazor:

```
$(function() {
    $('#Photo1').click(function () {
        $('#Uploader1').trigger("click");
    });

    $('#Photo2').click(function () {
        $('#Uploader2').trigger("click");
    });
});
```